# Auto Complete with re-arranging division

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a page displaying several categories in separate blocks. There is a search box for searching categories.
eg:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY ║ CATEGORY  ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

What I need is, When someone types, the blocks should re-arrange according to the matched characters (without page being refresh).
I am using php, jquery and of-course AJAX too.
Any help, please?

Comment: what you have written so far??

Comment: All the blocks say CATEGORY. How is that helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery Quicksand to achieve a similar effect:

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

You can quite easily bind to a text input for rearranging the grid.

Comment: Very close to what I need. How can I bind a search box with this?